# Sending email with Elixir and Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, mailer

I'm trying to send a confirmation email via Coherence.Mailer. But for some reason it will not actually send the email I can only see it in my console locally.

### CONFIG:

```
config :coherence,
  user_schema: Statcasters.Coherence.User,
  repo: Statcasters.Repo,
  module: Statcasters,
  web_module: StatcastersWeb,
  router: StatcastersWeb.Router,
  messages_backend: StatcastersWeb.Coherence.Messages,
  logged_out_url: "/",
  email_from_name: "Statcasters",
  email_from_email: "my@email.com",
  opts: [:authenticatable, :recoverable, :lockable, :trackable, :unlockable_with_token, :confirmable, :registerable]

config :coherence, StatcastersWeb.Coherence.Mailer,
  adapter: Swoosh.Adapters.Sendgrid,
  api_key: {:system, "API_KEY"}
```

I'm using Swoosh adapter with Coherence and according to the docs everything seems to be setup okay, but clearly I'm missing something.

Again, the problem is the email on sends locally it doesn't actually send to the intended recipient. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue seems similar to https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence/issues/161

Can you once try hardcoding the API_KEY and test,later on check if you are able to acccess API_KEY